# NSOutlineView outlineViewItemDidExpand notification appears before outline view redraws

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have NSOutlineView to show folders tree. I need to show progress indicator while folder in tree is expanding. I did it by delegate notifications:

```
-(void)outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self stopProgressIndicator];
}
```

and

```
-(void)outlineViewItemWillExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self stopProgressIndicator];
}
```

All works fine for small folders. But when I try to expand a folder with large number of subfolders my progress indicator stops before expansion results will shown in outline view.

As I understood, I need to stop my progress indicator not at item did expand but at outline view did finish redraw. How could I catch such event?